# Is the EM gauge potential on a trivial bundle?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry, field-theory, gauge-theory

I am studying mathematical gauge theory and its relations to physics (specifically field theory). The reading I’m doing (*Gauge Theory and Variational Principles* by Bleecker) explains that the EM field strength is independent of local section / gauge choice. Does this imply the PFB this strength describes is trivial? As in the whole bundle can be written as a product space?

Comment: As this review (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-9/issue-1/Review-David-D-Bleecker-Gauge-theory-and-variational-principles/bams/1183550979.full ) of Bleecker's book points out, what mathematicians and physicist mean by a "trivial" gauge bundle can be completely different.  However, I think that the answer to your question from the mathematician's viewpoint is *yes*—although I would want to recheck Bleecker's book before being sure of that.

Comment: Nontrivial bundles could be used to describe gauge potential around magnetic monopole.